# Editing OpenGL VBO with glBufferData removes parts of data

Tags: python, opengl, vbo, pyopengl

I have been trying to edit and/or update OpenGL VBOs using `glBufferData` to send data back to the buffer. In some cases, the data that I send it is larger than what was inside before, but that shouldn't matter since I am using `glBufferData` which overwrites the buffer's data anyway, right?

Well, when I run my program and add more faces to my buffer, it removes faces from another part of the buffer, instead of rendering them.

Here is my buffer updating code:

```
glBindVertexArray(vao)
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo)
draw_data = self.generate_vertex_data(data)
print(draw_data.size - previous_draw_data.size)
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, draw_data.nbytes, draw_data, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW
previous_draw_data = draw_data
```

I have checked, and `draw_data` is correct: the issue is with glBufferData, which is somehow limited to the size of the buffer. `draw_data` is a numpy array. Also, if I do not update the buffer, everything is fine.

When I update the buffer, if `draw_data` is larger than `previous_draw_data`, it renders the new faces but stops rendering other faces (I presume the faces that get removed are stored in the front of the buffer).

I would like to know why `glBufferData` is apparently limited to the size of the buffer even though it is supposed to resend the entire data.

Comment: I don't, actually! Thanks a million, you just solved about a week of head-scratching!

Answer (score 1):

So thanks to [httpdigest](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8623159/httpdigest), I now know that I was not updating the amount of faces in my call to `glDrawArrays`, and that effectively limited the amount of faces that could be rendered. It's as simple as that: I updated the amount of faces, and now it works as expected.